# Test does not display homeview correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to test my app and noticed that some widgets are not being found even though they are on the same page.

this is the code I'm using to search for widgets.

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('Search for button', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: HomeView(),
    ));
    final button = find.byType(BotaoRedirecionamentoInterno);
    expect(button, findsWidgets);
  });
}
```

after some research I found this command that lets me see what the test is seeing on the page.

```
flutter run test/view/home_view.dart
```

this is what the test sees in HomeView:

[image]

And that's how my app actually looks:

[image: enter code here]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are two problems : screen size and theme.

For the Theme, it looks like you are using a custom theme for your app because the app bar is a darker blue. You will need to use that same Theme in `MaterialApp` when pumping the widget in test because your test screen is still using the default app bar colour (light blue).

For the screen size:
In the `setUp` method you need to specify the screen size for which you want to test on.
Try this:

```
//Look up for the logical width and height of the display of the phone you want to test on
Size size = Size(390,844); //I think this is the Iphone12 size

//You need to look up the pixel ratio too, for phones its 
//usually 3  and tablets its 2 or maybe the other way around
double pixelRatio = 2;
final TestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding =
        TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await binding.setSurfaceSize(size);

//This is for portrait.For landscape just flip
binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = Size(
          size.shortestSide * device.devicePixelRatio,
          size.longestSide * device.devicePixelRatio)

binding.window.devicePixelRatioTestValue = device.devicePixelRatio;
```

and if you want to get the Screen Size in your `testWidgets` function in  `WidgetTester` callback, just call `tester.binding.renderView.size`.

Comment: Thats not the answer, everything is wrong on the test it does not render my images, dont have the back arrow, the text is in a different place, and for the size my app is responsible it should not render that way in any device.